# Multiple log rotate configuration in syslog.conf

Tags: linux, syslog

Is is possible to configure logrotate size and number of files for each file in syslog.conf

```
user.info                 /var/log/users.log (logrotate up to 1mb, up to 5 files)
user.debug;user.!info     /var/log/debug.log (logrotate up to 10mb, up to 10 files)
```

I'm using busybox syslogd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is is possible to configure logrotate size and number of files for each file in syslog.conf

No, it is not possible. Syslog only writes files.

`logrotate` is for log rotation configuration, with configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d`